# How do I split a string on a delimiter in zsh on MacOS 11.6.1?

Tags: string, macos, split, zsh

I want to split a string on a delimiter in zsh on MacOS 11.6.1. I looked at the following questions
[How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

I tried to reproduce its 2 most upvoted answers as follows:

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
IFS=';' read -ra ADDR <<< "$IN"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
  # process "$i"
done
```

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
while IFS=';' read -ra ADDR; do
  for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    # process "$i"
  done
done <<< "$IN"
```

but get the following output : `bad option: -a`

```
IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"
arrIN=(${IN//;/ })
echo ${arrIN[1]}                  # Output: john@home.com
```

but get the following output : `bla@some.com john@home.com` instead of `john@home.com`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `bash` and `zsh` are 2 different shells, so "in bash in zsh" doesn't make much sense. The error suggests you're using `zsh` in which case it would be `arrIN=(${(s[;])IN})`

Comment: Many thanks @jqurious! that worked! (I removed the "bash" from the question)

Comment: "bash" was still in title and tagging; I've removed it more thoroughly.

Comment: sorry about that. thank you @CharlesDuffy

Comment: According to the zsh man pages, `read` does not have an `-a` option. Perhaps you mean `-A`:  _-A  ... The first name is taken as the name of an array and all words are assigned to it_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` and avoid different shells particularities

```
awk '{sub(";","\n"); print}' <<<"bla@some.com;john@home.com" | xargs process
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer @DiegoTorresMilano. But when I tried your code (namely `awk '{sub(";","\n"); print}' <<<"bla@some.com;john@home.com" | xargs process`), I got the following error message: `xargs: process: Not a directory`

Comment: I thought you are invoking something called `process` from you example `# process "$i"`

Comment: Thanks for your your comment @DiegoTorresMilano. I replaced `process` with `echo` and got `bla@some.com john@home.com` (instead of `bla@some.com`)

Comment: Add `-L 1` to `xargs` to take 1 line at a time